# Import data to SQL Server from R without reading it

Tags: sql-server, r, import, rodbc

I need to import a list of files (txt) to SQL Server,  but I would like to do this without reading them in R. Is there a way to do this?

I know that this works, but I would like to avoid the read.table part?

```
tabla<-read.table("Cuota_Ingreso_201612.txt", header=TRUE)

require (RODBC)
    dbWar <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=XX;database=Warehouse;trusted_connection=true')

sqlSave(dbWar ,tablename='Cuota_Ingreso_201612',tabla, rownames=FALSE)
```

Thanks.

PS: I want to use R because is a big list of files and I want to write a loop to do it. Please don't answer using another program.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use R for that - just use whatever you want. Googling somethimg like "SQL server import csv" will be a good starting point..

Comment: You are confusing here. You say don't want to read them in `R`. Then you say you want to use `R`. And then you say don't answer using another program. So how do you want us to help you?

Comment: @WEI_DBA, I don't want to "read" them in R because I don't need to do anything in those files; I just need to upload them to sql server.

Comment: You mean loop through the files and bulk insert into the database? I think the command is bcp.exe in windows

Comment: So do everything in SQL Server. Create a stored proc to read the files into SQL and/or `bulk insert` as @chinsoon12 suggests.